# Best way to record a HTML Canvas/WebGL animation server-side into a video?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, three.js, phantomjs, node-canvas

I have a set of animations which I can make in Canvas (fabric.js) or WebGL (three.js). I need to record them automatically, server-side, through a script and output a video file.

The animations include:

1. Pictures
2. Videos (with audio)
3. Other animations/effects

I have researched a lot during last few months on this.

**Results**
1. *Use PhantomJS + FFMPEG*
Run HTML Canvas animations on headless browser(PhantomJS) and record with FFMPEG. **Here the issue is PhantomJS supports neither WebGL nor Video element.** http://phantomjs.org/supported-web-standards.html
2. *Use Websockets to send data back to server using DataURL*
Here again, we will need to run the animations on browser (**which we can't because we have to do everything on server**).
3. *[Use node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas)*
This is a library by TJ Holowaychuk which allows rendering HTML Canvas on Node.js. But it has its own limitations plus I haven't really explored this field much. 
(If someone could shed more light on this library)

If anyone has done it before or can guide me somewhere useful.
*All we need to do is use some data to create animations and record it into a video, everything on server side.*

Comment: `node-canvas` seems to be for 2d-contexts. I found the `node-webgl` package but have been unsuccessful to install its dependencies. However as a comment i have to write : if you want to record a webgl context (and use it as a rendering engine) to output videos for yourself, 1-by-1, you can do it server-side with `xhr` on a local server. But if you want to output videos to each connected user on the internet, just consider that it asks your serverSSS to have one CPU-GPU couple per visitor. I have been checking google for 'server-side 3D rendering' : there is nothing serious now with 2015 techs.

Comment: Also : what you describe is the way to use webgl as a rendering engine for yourself, that is why i wrote about it above. If you only look for the way to do it on a website your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64291/api-for-server-side-3d-rendering. But of all the answers there, none brings anything ^^

Comment: @Atrahasis What if we only want to record Canvas and NOT webGL. Can node-canvas be used for it? Does it support video and animations?

Comment: ccapture.js: https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js/

Comment: cccapture does on the browser side right ..?

Comment: @gaitat it needs animation to be run on the browser

Comment: @Stallion yes, so we cant use it

Comment: @Abhinav Sure, you could use ccapture.js with any browser with xvfb.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Can you elaborate a little? Or show some link or example?

Comment: I haven't used xvfb myself, but I've seen success with selenium+Firefox here on SO.

Comment: @abhinav Did you get the solution for this? Even i had the same problem statement wherein i had to record a webGL video. I am using plotly 3D Graph to be precise and tried all the options you mentioned above already. Also ccapture allows to stream the frames to a node server using ffmpegserver option. But it somehow freezes my UI while sending. If you have come up with any suitable solution, do let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use electron to render WebGL pages with BrowserWindow option "show" set to false and/or use xvfb-run to run headless.

Comment: Where does the rendering happen? Can I get a video for the scene that was just rendered saved on the filesystem?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think node-canvas supports the webgl context, so you'll
have to use a library built around 2d drawing, and it certainly
won't have support for any video codecs.

If you can get your animation to work using node-canvas, you can
grab the animated frames at a rate appropriate for your content,
something like this:

***Disclosure**: I've successfully used FFmpeg to encode a sequence
of externally generated images, but haven't tried the setInterval()
method below. In addition to the animation overhead itself, I don't
know how exporting a canvas to PNG files at 30 FPS would perform.*

```
// assuming "canvas" is asynchronously drawn on some interval

function saveCanvas(canvas, destFile) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const ext     = path.extname(destFile),
          encoder = '.png' === ext ?  'pngStream'
                                   : 'jpegStream';
    let writable = fs.createWriteStream(destFile),
        readable = canvas[encoder]();

    writable
      .on('finish', resolve)
      .on('error',  err => {
        let msg = `cannot write "${destFile}": ${err.message}`;
        reject(new Error(msg));
      });
    readable
      .on('end',   ()  => writable.end())
      .on('error', err => {
        let msg = `cannot encode "${destFile}": ${err.message}`;
        reject(new Error(msg));
      });
    readable.pipe(writable);
  });
}

const FPS = 30;

let frame    = 0,
    tasks    = [],
    interval = setInterval(() => tasks.push(
  saveCanvas(canvas, `frame_${frame++}.png`)), 1000 / FPS);

// when animation is done, stop timer
// and wait for images to be written
clearInterval(interval);

Promise.all(tasks).then(encodeVideo);

function encodeVideo() {
   // too much code to show here, but basically run FFmpeg
   // externally with "-i" option containing "frame_%d.png"
   // and "-r" = FPS. If you want to encode to VP9 + WEBM,
   // definitely see: http://wiki.webmproject.org/ffmpeg/vp9-encoding-guide
}
```

And then use FFmpeg to encode a sequence of images into a video.
For the code behind `encodeVideo()`, you can look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/erhhung/d29c9a8c099e39d4c1cb0e80cf508c99).

***Edit**: There may be an issue with `canvas.pngStream()` writing
incorrect frames while the animation loop continuously draws on
that one canvas--maybe a copy of the canvas needs to be created
per frame? That would surely create significant memory pressure.*

Answer (score 1):

I think that the chromium headless mode might support WebGL already and is another possibility. The video rendering part is yet to come though:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=781117

Answer (score 0):

[CCapture.js](https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js/) makes this pretty easy.